# How to keep my code window in VS large while working with Xaml

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2012, editor, design-time

I'm using Visual Studio to analyze some Xaml code. I work at a fairly low level, as such, the designer is completely pointless to me. So, I find it very annoying that I double click on a Xaml file to be greeted by a tiny code viewing window and a huge designer.

I've tried resizing the windows, and this kind of works. However, if I close the file and reopen it, the problem comes right back. Also, if I open other Xaml files, they'll still open with a huge designer

How it always looks when I first open a Xaml file:

[image]

How I want it to look every time I open a Xaml file:

[image]

Is there any way to get this configuration to "stick"? Is there some kind of setting I can set to configure the size of the design-time window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> XAML -> Miscellaneous.  Click the “Always open documents in full XAML view” checkbox. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Awesome! That did just what I wanted.